# Zener voltage is not stable

Tags: arduino, relay, zener

i have a made transformer less power supply to power a arduino board and and two relays. The circuit is designed to get 6v and a current of 150mA. after building the circuit i have connected one arduino and two relays across the output. The two relays are controlled by arduino. When i activate either one relay the output voltage across zener decreases to 5v but when i activate both of the relays at a time then the voltage decrease below 4V and the arduino restarts
Now i want to make the output voltage across the zener constat and stable how can i do that...? and why the voltage decreases with change in load...?[image]

Comment: Do you have some flyback diodes over your relay coils? Also what exactly is powered by these relays?

Comment: there are no flyback diodes used and the relays are used to power some bulbs

Comment: Scary circuit.  Can't you find a 5V wall wart?

Comment: Circuit Indigest

Comment: Add some flyback diodes before you blow up your arduino. And buy a 5V wall wart before you kill yourself.

Comment: You should learn from Dave Jones' Zener diode "fundamentals friday" [on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0ifJ4oVdG4) or [directly from his blog](https://www.eevblog.com/2016/08/07/eevblog-908-zener-diodes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zeners are poor at dynamic load voltage regulators because they need to consume the difference between the max current and minimum load current plus some minimal amount to have Vf as rated.

This places high power dissipation requirements and may be limited by your transformerless series cap impedance.

To improve this you may need to define your load requirements better and have increased storage capacitance or increased series capacitance and lower series resistance and higher power dissipation in the zener regulator.

Having underestimated your load current, you might think a SMPS is a better solution as offline regulators get costly with simple series RC dividers above 5W as the power lost in series is proportional to the VI drop to the regulator.

You should have defined your current needs better initially and choose lower current higher voltage relays like 24V then regulate down to 5 from there.

Also note that you do not have a low voltage common or ground in your circuit and safety is poor. For light bulbs ok, but not for user or other grounded computer interfaced supplies.

Comment: Great answer.  This article by the Bald Engineer has a more detailed explanation, and the discussion in the comments are enlightening: [Zener diodes make for lousy regulators (aka Reference and regulation are not the same thing)](https://www.baldengineer.com/zener-diode-regulators.html)

Comment: From my previous answers, which I elaborate on diode resistance , a 20mA white (65mW) is better at 5mA than Zeners due to the higher power rating is inverse with Zz or ESR or Rs whatever you want to call incremental resistance which defines the load regulation error from resistance ratio. Rs =k/Pd rated for k=0.25 to above 1 so a 65mW white is is about 15 ohms that rises but is much less than 50 ohms at 5mA

Answer (score 1):

This is a very dangerous power supply, as it will be "hot" relative to earth/ground.  For safety, you really should use a power transformer to isolate the DC output from the AC.

Check the voltage on C2 when the relays are on. It probably drops below 7 volts, and your load doesn't leave enough current to keep the Zener conducting.

The current drawn will cause varying voltage drops across R2, and also across C1 and R4.  You may have to increase the value of C1 to get enough voltage at C2 to keep the Zener diode conducting.

Answer (score 0):

To add what other folks have said about safety and Zeners being bad power supplies...

This supply will not produce enough current to power most relays.

\$
\begin{align}
X_{C1} &= \frac{1}{2\pi fC} \\
X_{C1} &= \frac{1}{2\pi * 50\rm{Hz} * 474 * 10^{-6}C} \\
X_{C1} &= \frac{1}{2\pi * 50\rm{Hz} * 0.474 * 10^{-6}C} \\
X_{C1} &= 6715\Omega
\end{align}
\$

Which means

\$
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{220}{X_{C1}} \\
I &= \frac{220}{6715}\\
I &= 32.8mA
\end{align}
\$

So... yeah.

Comment: this is just a referene circuit and i forget to mension that i have used a capacitor of 2.2 micro fared

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, all the same, this is not a great supply design.

Comment: @iqbalpalemad compute C ratio from peak voltage input ... 2.2/1000 * 230 *1.4 = 0.7V.???  1000uF seems too big

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing of the voltage is consequence of a lack of current. In order to get more current you have to increase the capacitor C1.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit can be considered as a constant current source. the value of current depends on the capacitance of c1. 
the value of current can be calculated as

```
    I = Vs/Xc

           Vs is the supply voltage (230V or 110V)
           Xc is the capacitive reactance 


     Xc = 1/2*pi*f*c

          f is the frequency of supply
          pi = 3.14
           c is the capacitance
```

now the we can use any zener diodes which can withstand these current 
and the maximum current that a zener can withstand can be calculated by

```
     Imax=P/V
        p is the power rating of diode
        V is the rated voltage of diode
```

for example for a 1W 5.6V diode the maximum current

```
    Imax = 1/5.6
         = 178mA
```

so if the Imax is greater than the supply current then the zener will provide a constant stable voltage

the value of resistance can be determined by power equation

```
      P= I2R
```